# transfer values in a datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two datepickers on a page, one of the month November and one on other on is on December. The datepickers are set to select a full week only.

Does someone know if it's possible to 'transfer' the data to the second datepicker, for example: select '27th of November' on datepicker 1, it should also select 1,2,3 December on the second datepicker.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered having the datepicker display more than one month at a time?

Comment: Didn't even know that was possible! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a problem with my response? Or have you found the answer elsewhere? Please close up the question if it is resolved :)

Comment: @Redgie I picked ShaneBlake's solution, was the most convenient. Thanks for your input though :).

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I picked @ShaneBlake's awnser, adding `numberOfMonths: [2,1]` in the datepicker config makes it show two calendars.

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = $("#datePicker1").val();
$("#datePicker2").val(date);
```